# Tag untagged: He's dead, Jim

Tags: discussion, tags

It is useless and should not exist in the first place! Kill it please!

Who, oh who has enough time to remove that nasty tag out of all those questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) posts occur when questions are migrated from other sites. It's a "site" special tag. There's no way to get rid of them except to go through and give them proper tags.

Comment: That is already done, just saying that if we spot them we should fix them ;)

Comment: Right, but just saying why it occurs :)

Comment: I know! :) <3 <3 <3 (< some hearts to make sure this is a valid comment!)

Comment: [tag:untagged] can also arise if a question's tag(s) is deleted by the single-use-tag killer; see [Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/48418#48418)

Answer (score 2):

I just edited all posts under the tag [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged), its dead, it was the worst 30 mins I spent on the site. Dont make me do it again!

If you see any more questions with the tag [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) please edit them your selfs or link them in the [Ask Ubuntu regulators room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) so someone can have a look at it.

Comment: Poor Bruno. Poor Bruno. ;)