# Retagging untagged questions "too minor"?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, retagging

Since when is retagging an untagged question "too minor"?

The community clearly thinks that retagging untagged questions is good (see links below), but still, half of my retags get rejected by being "to minor".

- [Please burninate the "untagged" tag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3869/please-burninate-the-untagged-tag)
- [Tag untagged: He's dead, Jim](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2784/tag-untagged-hes-dead-jim)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged (see description)

This peer review is very good especially for new users, like me, who do dumb things sometimes. But it can be really random sometimes and that is very frustrating...

Comment: Unfortunately even users with lots of reputation don't know everything about the site. The best thing to do when this happens is to post on meta to raise awareness (You did this!) and maybe bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let me put some points over i's.

1. Please read the tags excerpts before retagging. I reject **incorrectly** tagged ones.
2. [Closed] questions with [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) I tend to prefer just remove them. It clutters the site.
3. Don't just retag and forget about the title, or the body of the question. Fix as many problems you see with the posts, as is possible.

Comment: 1) I'm not talking about your "incorrert" rejects. You're absolutely right to reject it if I put the wrong tags on it.
2) How do I remove questions? How mucht rep do I need?

Comment: 3) That's true, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: 4) I saw a lot of "edit" approvals. What is that?

Comment: @Galgalesh 2) Just flag them with Other -> "Please, remove this question" 4) ??????

Comment: I see this: Braiam reviewed this 3 hours ago: Edit

Comment: @Galgalesh those are the ones that I corrected the tags.